# Chrome 78 bugs out when switching monitor layouts

Tags: multiple-monitors, google-chrome

I've got Chrome 78.0.3904.108 installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, and recently have been experiencing issues when changing my monitor layout. In other words, if I plug in a monitor with an HDMI cable while Chrome is open, or conversely if I un-plug a monitor while Chrome is open, Chrome basically becomes unusable.

Whatever tab is already open will become totally non-responsive. If I try and click on the tab bar to switch to another open tab, it won't. If I press Ctrl - T to launch a new tab, it won't. If I press Super - Arrow Key to try and resize it to fill to 50% of the screen, it sort of will but non-uniform portions of the screen will either be black or transparent, as you can see here:

[image: chrome bugging out]

The workaround I've found is to run `killall chrome` from the terminal and then re-launch it, at which point it's fine... at least until I change monitor layouts again! Has anyone else encountered this? And are there any fixes?

Comment: Same here! Super annoying! I'm surprised it's not already known & fixed.